# What is the maximum length of a string on a asp.net 1.1 web method call?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I've got a customer who wants to pass in a large string to one of our web services, beyond what it is really intended for, and it seems to be truncating data somewhere along the line.  Is there a maximum size for strings in web service calls?

It would be nice to say, "this isn't technically possible" rather than argue merits of limiting the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that there is a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a maximum length specifically for individual parameters, but there is a maxRequestLength for the entire request length itself.  This is configurable via your web.config, but a very large parameter could cause the request length to be too long.

Comment: That sounds like it would cause an exception, though, rather than a truncation of the string.

Comment: @quillbreaker You're right, but I thought that would be a good reason to give for the "not technically possible" route if you're getting anywhere close to that limitation.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the HttpRuntimeSection.MaxRequestLength property doesn't seem to exist (or at least isn't documented) for the 1.1 runtime - the MSDN page has a page for 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0 but not for 1.1.  Nice to know, at the least, that it could break if we updated the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Its 4 mb...

Look out for httpRuntime tag in machine.config